# How to remove some specific words from observations in Stata or R?

Tags: r, stata

I have done some research on internet and so far I have just found possibilities to remove the first/last letters from observations with `susbstr`, but not a command that would be like CTRL+F-findandreplace. The **trick** here is that I don't necessarily know where the words I want to drop are!

My dataset looks like this:

```
Hosp_code   Hosp    Hosplat Hosplon
RRK RRK - UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS BIRMINGHAM NHS FOUNDATION TRUST  52.453271   -1.9362835
RLU RLU - BIRMINGHAM WOMEN'S NHS FOUNDATION TRUST   52.453184   -1.9422432
5MX 5MX - HEART OF BIRMINGHAM TEACHING PCT  52.471575   -1.9367724
NO0 NO0 - HEALTHHARMONIE LIMITED    52.470965   -1.9243192
NLU NLU - SK:N (LASERCARE CLINICS LTD)  52.470838   -1.9220819
NXX NXX - SCRIVENS LTD  52.47148    -1.91341
AGL AGL - ADDITIONAL COMMUNITY MEDICAL SERVICES LTD 52.477343   -1.917197
5M1 5M1 - SOUTH BIRMINGHAM PCT  52.445922   -1.8928915
NQR NQR - PRIMECARE PRIMARY CARE    52.484113   -1.9173169
RXT RXT - BIRMINGHAM AND SOLIHULL MENTAL HEALTH NHS FOUNDATION TRUST    52.484113   -1.9173169
RRJ RRJ - THE ROYAL ORTHOPAEDIC HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST   52.421133   -1.9608273
RXK RXK - SANDWELL AND WEST BIRMINGHAM HOSPITALS NHS TRUST  52.48982    -1.9294268
RQ3 RQ3 - BIRMINGHAM CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST   52.485173   -1.8944604
RYW RYW - BIRMINGHAM COMMUNITY HEALTHCARE NHS TRUST 52.487323   -1.8858108
5PG 5PG - BIRMINGHAM EAST AND NORTH PCT 52.491369   -1.886036
NIT NIT - SOUTH DOC SERVICES LIMITED HQ 52.401796   -1.9620201
RR1 RR1 - HEART OF ENGLAND NHS FOUNDATION TRUST 52.477876   -1.8275305
NIS NIS - COVENTRY AND WARWICKSHIRE DIAGNOSTIC SERVICES LIMITED 52.462504   -1.8159336
NDT NDT - WEST MIDLANDS DIAGNOSTIC SERVICES LTD 52.462504   -1.8159336
5PF 5PF - SANDWELL PCT  52.523328   -2.0026388
TAJ TAJ - BLACK COUNTRY PARTNERSHIP NHS FOUNDATION TRUST    52.519255   -2.0188053
NEP NEP - TICCS ULTRASOUND LIMITED  52.510017   -1.8113152
NL7 NL7 - ASSURA VERTIS URGENT CARE CENTRES (BIRMINGHAM)    52.542091   -1.8778985
NNT NNT - ASSURA KINGSTANDING   52.542091   -1.8778985
5QW 5QW - SOLIHULL PCT  52.391695   -1.8081752
NR9 NR9 - JOHN TAYLOR HOSPICE COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY    52.527341   -1.8234016
RYK RYK - DUDLEY AND WALSALL MENTAL HEALTH PARTNERSHIP NHS TRUST    52.508312   -2.0844533
```

I'd like to remove:
- The first three letters (e.g. `RRK -`)
- Any mention of `"LTD" "LTD "LIMITED" "HQ" "LLP" "TRUST" "FOUNDATION TRUST"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: or http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_replace_all

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you get longitude and latitude for NHS organisations?

Comment: I searched them manually hahahha

Comment: What's `susbstr`? Stata has `substr()` and `subinstr()`.  Either way, please say whether that's Stata or R syntax, and correct any typos. Ctrl-F is usually just "find" in Windows programs I know, but note that many readers here will be using other operating systems.

Comment: In stata, you could try a long line of `replace ... subinstr()` command/functions, or a shorter number of `replace ... regexr()` command/functions. The second requires some knowledge of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using R. Two strategies, the first uses base R function, the second use the package [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html). Both uses 3 steps: i) remove the first 7 characters; ii) remove the patterns we don't want, iii) trim any remaining space.

```
# a subset of your data.frame making your question reproducible
df <- structure(list(Hosp = c("NXX - SCRIVENS LTD", "AGL - ADDITIONAL COMMUNITY MEDICAL SERVICES LTD", 
                              "5M1 - SOUTH BIRMINGHAM PCT", "NQR - PRIMECARE PRIMARY CARE", 
                              "RXT - BIRMINGHAM AND SOLIHULL MENTAL HEALTH NHS FOUNDATION TRUST", 
                              "RRJ - THE ROYAL ORTHOPAEDIC HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST", 
                              "RXK - SANDWELL AND WEST BIRMINGHAM HOSPITALS NHS TRUST")),
                .Names = "Hosp", row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

> df$Hosp
[1] "NXX - SCRIVENS LTD"                                              
[2] "AGL - ADDITIONAL COMMUNITY MEDICAL SERVICES LTD"                 
[3] "5M1 - SOUTH BIRMINGHAM PCT"                                      
[4] "NQR - PRIMECARE PRIMARY CARE"                                    
[5] "RXT - BIRMINGHAM AND SOLIHULL MENTAL HEALTH NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"
[6] "RRJ - THE ROYAL ORTHOPAEDIC HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"       
[7] "RXK - SANDWELL AND WEST BIRMINGHAM HOSPITALS NHS TRUST" 

#base R functions -----------
gsub(" $", "", gsub("LTD|LIMITED|HQ|LLP|TRUST|FOUNDATION TRUST", "", substr(df$Hosp, 7, nchar(df$Hosp))))

# a function to do it
nice_hospname <- function(x){
  gsub(" $", "", gsub("LTD|LIMITED|HQ|LLP|TRUST|FOUNDATION TRUST", "", substr(x, 7, nchar(x))))
}
# you can use it with:
nice_hospname(df$Hosp)

# with stringr package --------
library(stringr)
df$Hosp %>% str_sub(7) %>% str_replace("LTD|LIMITED|HQ|LLP|TRUST|FOUNDATION TRUST", "") %>% str_trim()

[1] "SCRIVENS"                                   "ADDITIONAL COMMUNITY MEDICAL SERVICES"     
[3] "SOUTH BIRMINGHAM PCT"                       "PRIMECARE PRIMARY CARE"                    
[5] "BIRMINGHAM AND SOLIHULL MENTAL HEALTH NHS"  "THE ROYAL ORTHOPAEDIC HOSPITAL NHS"        
[7] "SANDWELL AND WEST BIRMINGHAM HOSPITALS NHS"

# a function to do it
nice_hospname2 <- function(x){
  x %>% str_sub(7) %>% str_replace("LTD|LIMITED|HQ|LLP|TRUST|FOUNDATION TRUST", "") %>% str_trim()
}
# you can use it with:
nice_hospname2(df$Hosp)


library(stringr)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here a similar strategy using Stata. In the future, be considerate and use `dataex` to generate your data example.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str68 Hosp
"RRK - UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS BIRMINGHAM NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"      
"RLU - BIRMINGHAM WOMEN'S NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"                   
"5MX - HEART OF BIRMINGHAM TEACHING PCT"                          
"NO0 - HEALTHHARMONIE LIMITED"                                    
"NLU - SK:N (LASERCARE CLINICS LTD)"                              
"NXX - SCRIVENS LTD"                                              
"AGL - ADDITIONAL COMMUNITY MEDICAL SERVICES LTD"                 
"5M1 - SOUTH BIRMINGHAM PCT"                                      
"NQR - PRIMECARE PRIMARY CARE"                                    
"RXT - BIRMINGHAM AND SOLIHULL MENTAL HEALTH NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"
"RRJ - THE ROYAL ORTHOPAEDIC HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"       
"RXK - SANDWELL AND WEST BIRMINGHAM HOSPITALS NHS TRUST"          
"RQ3 - BIRMINGHAM CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"       
"RYW - BIRMINGHAM COMMUNITY HEALTHCARE NHS TRUST"                 
"5PG - BIRMINGHAM EAST AND NORTH PCT"                             
"NIT - SOUTH DOC SERVICES LIMITED HQ"                             
"RR1 - HEART OF ENGLAND NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"                     
"NIS - COVENTRY AND WARWICKSHIRE DIAGNOSTIC SERVICES LIMITED"     
"NDT - WEST MIDLANDS DIAGNOSTIC SERVICES LTD"                     
"5PF - SANDWELL PCT"                                              
"TAJ - BLACK COUNTRY PARTNERSHIP NHS FOUNDATION TRUST"            
"NEP - TICCS ULTRASOUND LIMITED"                                  
"NL7 - ASSURA VERTIS URGENT CARE CENTRES (BIRMINGHAM)"            
"NNT - ASSURA KINGSTANDING"                                       
"5QW - SOLIHULL PCT"                                              
"NR9 - JOHN TAYLOR HOSPICE COMMUNITY INTEREST COMPANY"            
"RYK - DUDLEY AND WALSALL MENTAL HEALTH PARTNERSHIP NHS TRUST"    
end

gen work = substr(Hosp, 7, .)
replace work = ustrregexra(work, " *(LTD|LIMITED|HQ|LLP|TRUST|FOUNDATION TRUST)", "")
leftalign // from SSC, to install, type: ssc install leftalign
list
```

Comment: ustrregexra() is available only in Stata 14. If you are working with a previous version of Stata use regexr() instead.